# UnityEngine Are you missing an assembly reference? in Unity 3d v 5.2.3f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

Assets/Standard Assets/Utility/ForcedReset.cs(3,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name Scene Management' does not exist in the namespace ,UnityEngine Are you missing an assembly reference?

> error CS0234 The type or namespace name ,SceneManagement' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;`

Comment: using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

[RequireComponent(typeof (GUITexture))]
public class ForcedReset : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        // if we have forced a reset ...
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("ResetObject"))
        {
            //... reload the scene
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetSceneAt(0).name);
        }
    }
}
----- but not work -----

Comment: Never put code in comments, update your question with a edit and put the code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SceneManager` namespace was added in **Unity 5.3**. Since you are using **5.2.3**, it won't be available. The solution to your problem is to update to **5.3** or above. If you can't update for some reason, use  `Application.LoadLevel(0);`

EDIT:

After your comment. Look at the image below:

[image]

**You can load level by index**:

```
Application.LoadLevel(0);
Application.LoadLevel(1);
Application.LoadLevel(2);
```

**Or by name**:

```
Application.LoadLevel("test");
```

**File**->**Build Settings...** then drag the scene name into the **Build Settings** so that they will be accessible by code.

Comment: how i can use Application.LoadLevel(0); ??

Comment: @MurtadaAltaee Updated the answer.

Comment: i update unity to Unity 5.3 , but in File->Build Settings -> Android (Build and Run) not work.

Comment: I never said **Build and Run** anywhere in my answer. I said, **drag** the scene to the Build Settings so that it can be accessible from code. This answer should solve your namespace problem.